# How do I run a single UnitTest from rocket-chip?

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

Specifically I'd like to run AXI4XbarTest from rocket-chip/src/main/scala/amba/axi4/Xbar.scala.  It looks this test should be run by the regression tests, but if I go into the regression directory and run

```
export SUITE=UnittestSuite
make emulator-ndebug
```

I end with the error:

```
make VM_PARALLEL_BUILDS=1 -C /home/ben/Code/rocket-chip/emulato/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.unittest.AMBAUnitTestConfig -f VTestHarness.mk
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ben/Code/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/freechips.rocketchip.unittest.AMBAUnitTestConfig'
make[2]: VTestHarness.mk: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'VTestHarness.mk'.  Stop.
```

But really, I don't want to run the regression tests, I just want to run a single unit test, and I'm having trouble extracting how to do that from the Makefiles.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope.  I got distracted by something else before I got around to posting on the mailing list.  What I was really looking for was a public project with decent tests that I could learn from.  Is rocket-chip the best repo to look at or is there a better one.

Comment: That looks like a Verilator output is missing.
Did you build the emulator (a Verilated version of the rocket chip, ie. the output of the Chisel->Verilog flow put through Verilator) by going into emulator and running make in there?